# Query to get count of distinct value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have tried this below query in MySQL but not working.

```
select count(*)
from (
      select count distinct(RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN)
      from rbt_activation_details_log
      where RADL_ACTIVE ='A'
      group by RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN
     );
```

Comment: What output do you need? What's wrong with just `select count distinct(RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN) from rbt_activation_details_log where RADL_ACTIVE ='A' group by RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN`?

Comment: Mysql Server version is : 5.0.22-log

Comment: @jim : I need the Total count . i am getting below error  mysql> select count distinct(RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN) from rbt_activation_details_log where RADL_ACTIVE ='A' group by RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct(RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN) from rbt_activation_details_log where RADL_ACTIVE ' at line 1
mysql>

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(distinct column_whose_distinct_values_you_want_to_count) 
from rbt_activation_details_log 
where RADL_ACTIVE ='A' 
group by RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN
```

You're grouping and counting on the same column, so this will always give you `1` as result.

EDIT:

Then simply omit the group by clause

```
select count(distinct RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN) 
from rbt_activation_details_log 
where RADL_ACTIVE ='A'
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that on fast reading. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I need the Total count . for example in oracle this query is working fine and giving the count select count(*) from ( select count(distinct tariff_id_n)from TARIFF_PLANS WHERE STATUS_N=1 group by TARIFF_ID_N); output 126

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN)
FROM rbt_activation_details_log
WHERE RADL_ACTIVE = 'A'
GROUP BY RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Count(UNIQUE(radl_request_msisdn))
FROM   rbt_activation_details_log
WHERE  radl_active = 'A'
GROUP  BY radl_request_msisdn
```

Comment: @user2696461 I have edited the answer according to your table info. This should do it.

Answer (score 1):

By your query:

```
select count(*) 
from
    (select count distinct(RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN)
    from rbt_activation_details_log
    where RADL_ACTIVE ='A' group by RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN);
```

Appears as you want retrieve all distinct count not grouped by radl_request_msisdn. If so than you rewrite your query in this way:

```
    select count distinct(RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN)
    from rbt_activation_details_log
    where RADL_ACTIVE ='A';
```

Instead if you want to grouped, the query will be:

```
    select count distinct(RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN)
    from rbt_activation_details_log
    where RADL_ACTIVE ='A' group by RADL_REQUEST_MSISDN;
```

Comment: i m not getting the desired result . i need the total count. these query will list out all the columns and i do not want.My query working fine in oracle but for mysql how i need to modify plz suggest

Comment: @user2696461: Dear, my queries return only numbers! The first returns a distinct count of all rbt_activation_details_log; the second returns a distinct count depends by rbt_activation_details_log. Using ob subquery to get count of count is not always correct.

Comment: Yes joe you are correct and query giving output correctly. There are around 100000 count if i do not use distinct. i want the distinct count. i do not want to list all those count

Comment: @user2696461: Ok, so you will use my first query ;). Have a nice day